# Solr could not load MySQL JDBC Driver

Tags: java, mysql, apache, jdbc, solr

I am using `Solr 4.6.1` on `Mac`. I try to figure out how to use data import to load data from `MySQL`. But I end up with fail to load JDBC Driver class. Here is what I did:

Put `mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar` to `~/Tools/Solr/example/lib/`

1.Configure `~/Tools/Solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/data-config.xml`:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
          driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" 
          user="root" 
          password="root"/>
<document>
<entity name="SolrTest" 
        query="select * from SolrTest">
   <field column="ID" name="id"/>
   <field column="Name" name="name"/>
   <field column="Class" name="class"/>
   <field column="Score" name="score"/>
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

2.Configure `~/Tools/Solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml`:

add the following under `< config> < /config>`

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" 
                class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

also

```
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

3.Add the following to `~/Tools/Solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml`:

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="class" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="score" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Then run

```
java -jar start.jar
```

When I go to

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/dataimport//dataimport
```

it shows

```
No information available (idle)
```

When I click the execute button, I got the following error message:

> 31537 [Thread-15] ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter  – Full Import
>   failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could
>   not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1    at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:270)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:476)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:457)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could
>   not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1    at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:410)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:323)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:231)
>     ... 3 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could
>   not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1    at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.createConnectionFactory(JdbcDataSource.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.init(JdbcDataSource.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.getDataSourceInstance(DataImporter.java:383)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ContextImpl.getDataSource(ContextImpl.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.init(SqlEntityProcessor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.init(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:427)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:408)
>     ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to
>   load com.mysql.jdbc.Driver or
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:916)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.createConnectionFactory(JdbcDataSource.java:114)
>     ... 12 more Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error
>   loading class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:470)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:401)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:906)
>     ... 13 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
>   java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:789)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:454)
>     ... 15 more

How to solve this?

Comment: Create a lib folder directly under solr folder and place the jar file, like - ~/Tools/Solr/lib/mysqlxxx.jar

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Create a folder inside your solr installation directory. (say solr-4.6.1/**lib**)
2. Place the mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar inside the folder.
3. Edit solrconfig.xml and put the jar's path

   `<lib dir="../../../lib/" regex="mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar" />`
4. Restart Solr.

Also please check your URL. It's having `//`

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/dataimport//dataimport
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I got another problem. When I click on the Execute button under Dataimport page. It keeps indexing and never stops. Actually the data are already imported. I have to click abandon then it shows indexing completed. Why I have this problem?

Comment: IMPORTANT: Restart Solr. Restart Solr. Restart Solr. many guides don't tell you that and I spent hours like an idiot editing config files for nothing...

Comment: Where is that jar file, I can't see it in my system?

Answer (score 2):

So for those unfortunate souls who end up here. I'm using the latest Solr Docker image (8.4) which is configured so that the solr Unix-user doesn't have any permissions to create/delete folders and whatnot. For some reason I managed to create a `lib` file which I took for being a directory. After debugging a while I noticed this error, and promptly just changed the

`<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />`

to

`<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/dataimporthandler/" regex=".*\.jar" />`

where my `postgresql-42.2.10.jar` driver is. Otherwise all the other steps apply (edit `solrconfig.xml`, add `data-config.xml`, add `schema.xml`, copy `posgresql-*.jar` to the container's `/opt/solr-8.4.1/contrib/dataimporthandler`). Maybe one thing worth of mentioning is that I used Docker's internal network URL instead of localhost: `url="jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5600/my_postgres_db"` but I don't think it matters.

And oh, remember to restart Solr after adding the files / making changes =).